# background-image still not working despite trying all the Stackoverflow recommendations

Tags: html, css, background-image

The path to the image file is correct because  works perfectly fine.  The image file is in the same directory as the index.html.  The stylesheet is also in the same directory and is working with no problem.  I tried with smaller images/bigger images, JPG files or PNG files, tried resizing the div box or setting it to auto.  I tried using Chrome and Firefox, but none are working despite the element inspector showing no issues with background-image.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
div {
    background-image: url("picture.jpg");
}
```

Edit: I followed the advise of adding the height setting, but still doesn't work.

index.html

```
<main>
    <div class="hero-image">

    </div>
</main>
```

style.css

```
.hero-image {
    background-image: url("picture.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: Try refreshing the page with `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `R`.

Comment: Your `div` has no height value defined, so it is 0 by default.

Comment: `tried everything that people recommended on Stackoverflow` --> how can you conclude that you have tried *everything*?

Comment: Your above code works correctly, and assuming you have uploaded all relevant files and cleared your cache, it should work as expected. Please ensure you have provided a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to see the background, it should be the `height` and `width` properties of the div. Like this:

```
div {
 height:400px;
 width:400px;
 background:url(image.png);
}
```

As you can see:

```css
.a, .b {
  background:url("https://picsum.photos/300")
}

.a {
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
```

`.b` is doesn't show.